# a:link a:active together inside container

Tags: html, css

I have a quick question. How can I make css below to work (without separating link, active, visited)? It has to be inside container "divContainer"

> ```
> .divContainer a:link, a:active, a:visited {
>
>     color: blue;
>
> }
> ```

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only group (`,`) *complete* selectors.

```
.divContainer a:link, 
.divContainer a:active,
.divContainer a:visited {
```